# VB 2010 Download Online File

Tags: vb.net, excel, download, excel-2010

I am currently trying to download a file from our companies website and placing it on the users desktop, i have tried this code with other websites with JPGs and it did work, but for some reason when i'm trying to download a XLSM file from our website (which can only be accessed if you are logged in on our companies computers i believe) it gives me a 401 error message. I don't know what i am doing wrong. The code i have so far is:

```
Private sub button1_click(sender as system.object, e as system.eventargs) handles button1.click
my.computer.network.downloadfile("http://portal.###.ws/canada/depts/MEG_IPT/Shared%20Documents/MEG%20Master%20Schedule.xlsm", "L:\User\KD\testing.xlsm")
end sub
```

I have blocked some of the URL to the actual website with ### for security reasons, regardless people outside of our company can not access it. One more thing i would like to note is that when users do click that link, there is a pop up message that asks if the user would like to OPEN, SAVE, or SAVE AS. so i am not sure if this is whats causing the 401 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use overloadded method with username and password.

```
Private sub button1_click(sender as system.object, e as system.eventargs) handles button1.click
my.computer.network.downloadfile("http://portal.###.ws/canada/depts/MEG_IPT/Shared%20Documents/MEG%20Master%20Schedule.xlsm", "L:\User\KD\testing.xlsm",yourusername, yourpassword)
end sub
```

For more information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y(v=vs.90).aspx

For more information about error 401:
http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting 401 "from your application". You're getting 401 from the server.
HTTP.401 is pretty self explanatory: you're not authorised to access that particular resource.
If this portal requires authentication (NTLM) you should provide valid credentials so the webserver can authorise the resource access.
Here is an example using WebClient (internally and potentially the same implementation as Network.DownloadFile) that let's you specify user credentials.

```
Dim WC As New Net.WebClient
WC.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pwd")
WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("your url"), "local path")
```

You should add an handler for the Complete event, either by AddHandler or "WithEvents" keyword.